# c# HttpWebRequest Editing the request headers before they are sent

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

If I want to modify the request headers (full control) but still use the HttpWebRequest class, do I need to make some sort of extension class where the string headers are public?

Or is it not even possible at all?

I want to be able to fully control the headers of HttpWebRequest:

Pseudocode:

```
HttpWebRequest r = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://google.com");
r.Headers = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n"

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
```

Comment: Most header have built in properties and have to be modified by the property.  For example r.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;

Comment: But at some point it should be possible to edit the outgoing data (at socket level)

Comment: Why?  That would require creating you own http class.  The Net Library doesn't have access to the socket through a HttpWebRequest unless you create a class that inherits the WebRequest or use C++.  The Managed Net Library has lots of restrictions.   Http uses TCP at the transport level which is the socket.  TCP is limited to ~1500 bytes per datagram.  The Http Class manages the TCP automatically.  I don't think you want to write code at socket level.